# powerline adpater (ethernet) and recessed LED lights in the same room (same circuit)

Tags: led

I used to have computer, laser printer and a powerline adapter off the same outlet in the same room with no issues. I added recessed lights in the room, and now this trips the circuit breaker. The trip is not immediate and when I isolated the trigger in stages, I found that adding the powerline adapter as the last item (on circuit) triggered a trip. Is there something in the LED bulb circuit which would interact with the powerline adapter in such a way as to trigger a trip?

The installation is tied to a AFCI breaker: Siemens AFCI type QAF issue 1047
The breaker is from 2010. Do I need to replace the breaker and if yes what model?

Comment: Is this a standard breaker, a GFCI, or an AFCI? What make and model is it?

Comment: Siemens AFCI breaker from 2010. Tyoe QAF issue 1047.

Comment: Well, you're married to AFCI breakers listed to go in Siemens panels.  You can't swap any old brand, even if they semi-fit.  I'm not surprised an AFCI and a powerline network adapter wouldn't play nice.  Why do you have AFCI?  Do you also have real grounding?  For that matter, is there an issue preventing you from using WiFi?

Comment: Can you swap the AFCI for a newer Siemens unit with the indicator LEDs on it (I believe that's the primary change from a QAF to a QAF2 type?)